# Inside Foreachloop button click Value not pass to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass the **ID** Value to the controller on the button click Ajax Post request. But it couldn't work. The button resides within the Foreach loop. Here I am trying to pass the ID value but later on, I want to pass the **model** value. If possible please give me a solution for both.

**Controller Method:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Job_details(int id)
        {
            int ids = 0;
            return Json(new { result = "Redirect"});
        }
```

**View Code:**

```
@model IEnumerable<OnlineRecruitmentMst>
@{
    var options = Model.OrderBy(i => i.VacancyID).ToList();
}
 @for (int i = 0; i < options.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div id="loopOption" class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-xl-10">
                    <!-- single-job-content -->
                    <div class="single-job-items mb-30">
                        <div class="job-items">
                            <div class="company-img">
                                <a href="job_details.cshtml"><img src="assets/img/icon/job-list1.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="job-tittle">
                                <a><h4 id="VacPost">@options[i].Post</h4></a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="VacDept"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>@options[i].Department</li>
                                    <li id="VacNumber">Numer Of Vacancy: @options[i].NumberOfVacancy</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="items-link f-right">
                            <button id="btnPost" type="submit" class="btn head-btn1" data-id="@options[i].VacancyID" value="@options[i].VacancyID">View Details</button>
                            <span id="VacEndDate" class="alert-danger">End Date : @options[i].EndDate</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

**Script Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $(document).on("click", "#btnPost", function (e) {
             debugger;
             e.preventDefault();
             var Vacid = $(this).val();
                          
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/home/job_details/",
                data: JSON.stringify(Vacid),
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("AJAX request successfully completed");
                    if (response.result == 'Redirect') {
                        window.location = '@Url.Action("JobVacancy", "Home")';
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error occurred.");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In your loop your are generating multiple items with the same id `btnPost` ID must be unique. Use classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to pass the model value. If possible please give me a solution
> for both.

For how to pass id,you could refer:

View:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $(document).on("click", "#btnPost", function (e) {
             debugger;
             e.preventDefault();
             var Vacid = $(this).val();

             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "/home/job_details/",
                 data: { id: Vacid },  //change here
                //contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',  //remove this
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("AJAX request successfully completed");
                    if (response.result == 'Redirect') {
                        window.location = '@Url.Action("JobVacancy", "Home")';
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error occurred.");
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

For how to pass model,here is a working demo,you need to modify your element id with dynamic index:

Model:

```
public class OnlineRecruitmentMst
{
    public int VacancyID { get; set; }
    public string Post { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfVacancy { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<OnlineRecruitmentMst>
@{
    var options = Model.OrderBy(i => i.VacancyID).ToList();
}
@for (int i = 0; i < options.Count(); i++)
{
    <div id="loopOption" class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-xl-10">
            <!-- single-job-content -->
            <div class="single-job-items mb-30">
                <div class="job-items">
                    <div class="company-img">
                        <a href="job_details.cshtml"><img src="assets/img/icon/job-list1.png" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="job-tittle">
                        <a><h4 id="VacPost_@i">@options[i].Post</h4></a>    @*change id here*@
                        <ul>
                            @*change id here*@
                            <li id="VacDept_@i"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>@options[i].Department</li>
                            <li id="VacNumber_@i">Numer Of Vacancy: @options[i].NumberOfVacancy</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="items-link f-right">
                    @*add onclick function here*@
                    <button onclick="Click('@options[i].VacancyID','@i')" id="btnPost" type="submit" class="btn head-btn1" data-id="@options[i].VacancyID" value="@options[i].VacancyID">View Details</button>
                    @*change id here*@
                    <span id="VacEndDate_@i" class="alert-danger">End Date : @options[i].EndDate</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Click(vacid,index) {
            var VacNumber = $("#VacNumber_" + index).text();
            var data = VacNumber.split(":");
            var Vacancy = data[data.length - 1];
            var VacEndDate = $("#VacEndDate_" + index).text();
            var data2 = VacEndDate.split(":");
            var EndDate = data2[data2.length - 1];
            //pass the model
            var model = {
                VacancyID: vacid,
                Post: $("#VacPost_" + index).text(),
                Department: $("#VacDept_" + index).text(),
                NumberOfVacancy: Vacancy,
                EndDate: EndDate,
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/home/job_details/",
                data: JSON.stringify(model),  //change here
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("AJAX request successfully completed");
                    if (response.result == 'Redirect') {
                        window.location = '@Url.Action("JobVacancy", "Home")';
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error occurred.");
                }
            });
        }
 
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Job_details([FromBody] OnlineRecruitmentMst OnlineRecruitmentMst)
{
    //...
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: If the just changed so he didn't duplicated id then it would work just fine. Aka change `#btnPost` to `.btnPost` and it would work

Comment: @Rena For ID passing it works perfectly for me. But when I tried to pass the model at the controller end model received as null for me.

Comment: Hi @Rushil,Be sure you have copied my whole code and the model should be the same as mine.If you do not know how to change your code,you could provide your code which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Rena I have used the same code as you have provided, but I don't find the solution. Every time my model is getting nulled at the controller end.

Comment: Be sure your controller is not ApiController.And remember to add `[FromBody]` in your action.Remember to add `contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',` in your ajax.

Comment: @Rena I have checked everything and it is perfect in all aspects. Is there any way I can do it?